# USA state map in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the code map in R but I keep getting this error... What should I do?

```
map('usa')
Error in eval(parse(text = dbname)) : 
  cannot open file '~/R/win-library/3.5/maps/data/Rdata.rdb': No such file or directory
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(parse(text = dbname)) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation

library("maps")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried moving `library("maps")` to the beginning rather than end? This should be first.

Comment: Yes, I had it first.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the installation of the package, maybe as a result of a recent update to the latest R version (3.5). I would try to run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`. Or maybe reinstall the `maps` package.

Comment: Also, `library("maps")` should really be the first line of your code, as pointed out by @CephBirk

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the data already stored in a file, so try with:

```
library("maps")    
load('~/R/win-library/3.5/maps/data/Rdata.rdb')
```

or try with:

```
library("maps")
map('usa')
```